# Reading integers from a file separated with spaces

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I am having a file which is holding integers like this:

```
11_12_34_1987_111_
```

where `_` represents spaces and i want to store them in integer array having max size suppose 100. I have tried this

```
    i=0;
    while((c=fgetc(f))!=EOF)
    {

        fscanf( f, "%d", &array[i] );
        i++;
    }
```

but printing this array gives me infinite values on my Screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505297/reading-comma-seperated-values-from-a-file-storing-in-a-1d-and-2d-array?rq=1

Comment: `where _ represents spaces` So why you write `11_12_34_1987_111` instead it write `11 12 34 1987 111`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgetc` reads the next character from the stream `f` and returns it as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`. So you are storing the (ascii) codes of the characters read from the stream.

You should read them as integers using `fscanf` or a combination of `fgets` and `sscanf` to read integers from the stream. You can check the return value of `fscanf` for `1` and keep reading from the file. Here's what I suggest.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
int array[100];
int i = 0, retval;

if(fp == NULL) {
    printf("error in opening file\n");
    // handle it
}

// note the null statement in the body of the loop
while(i < 100 && (retval = fscanf(fp, "%d", &array[i++])) == 1) ; 

if(i == 100) {
    // array full
}

if(retval == 0) {
    // read value not an integer. matching failure
}

if(retval == EOF) {
    // end of file reached or a read error occurred
    if(ferror(fp)) {
        // read error occurred in the stream fp
        // clear it
        clearerr(fp);
    }
}

// after being done with fp
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: is it works for if `input.txt` contain in format like `11_12_34_1987_111_222`?

Comment: @Jayesh OP has mentioned that `_` represents spaces. So yes, it will work.

Comment: If i not wrong then `_` must be parsed from code or extract the each element by token `_`. But anyway if OP want this then it's ok.